# IronPython - Unexpected Token 'from' error is encountered after 'Import pyautogui'

Tags: c#, python, ironpython, pyautogui

Newbie to python/ironpython here.
i wanted to import pyautogui library/module via IronPython in CSharp.
Pyautogui has already been installed via Pip and is already in standard library 
(Also have Python 3.6 installed)

Goal is to be able to get my inputs via c# and change my python scripts for more flexible automation.

However, when running, i am getting an error saying
"Unexpected Token 'from'".

This is also the case with import os.

Need your feedback on this please.

.NET Framework = 4.5
IronPython 2.7.9
PyAutoGui 0.9.39

i have made sure that the search paths to the libraries has been added.

NOTE: import pyautogui and import os works using python 3.6

--- Code Here ----

```
        Console.WriteLine("Input Sample: ");
        Console.ReadLine();

        var pythonObj = Python.CreateEngine();
        var searchPaths = pythonObj.GetSearchPaths();
        searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\Lib");
        searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\Lib\site-packages");
        pythonObj.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
        try
        {
            pythonObj.Execute("import pyautogui");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

i should be able to open a browser after the successful import of pyautogui.

Screenshots are also available below
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tMCW.png //ErrorEncountered
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUILt.png //StackTrace
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZOhu.png //StackTrace

Hoping to get help from you guys on this.
Thnks

Comment: hi! can anyone help me on this?